# Spring @Async method inside a Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have this service bean with a *sync* method calling the internal *async* method:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    public worker() {
        asyncJob();
    }
    
    @Async
    void asyncJob() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

The trouble is that the `asyncJob` is not really called in *async* way.
I found that this doesn't work because an internal call skips the **AOP proxy**.

So I try to **self-refer** the bean:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    MyService mySelf;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext cnt;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        mySelf=(MyService)cnt.getBean("myService");
    }
    
    
    public void worker() {
        mySelf.asyncJob();
    }
    
    @Async
    void asyncJob() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

**It fails**. Again no *async* call.

So I tried to **divide it** in two beans:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    MyAsyncService myAsyncService;

    public void worker() {
        myAsyncService.asyncJob();
    }
}

@Service
public class MyAsyncService {

    @Async
    void asyncJob() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

**Fails again**.

The only working way is to call it from a **Controller Bean**:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    MyAsyncService myAsyncService;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void worker() {
        myAsyncService.asyncJob();
    }

}

@Service
public class MyAsyncService {

    @Async
    public void asyncJob() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

But in this case it is a service job. Why I cannot call it from a *service*?

Comment: Are you sure you have `@EnableAsync` turned on in the first examples?

Comment: The first example will not work as a call from one service method to another method within in the same service class will not go via the proxy. The second example should definitely work though.

Comment: There is not @EnableAsync annotation, but I think this is already enabled (otherwise the last example can not work...).

Comment: `@Controller` and `@Service` are similar when it comes to classpath scanning. The second example should work just fine, as the third. If you want the first example to work, you need to use AspectJ.

Comment: I can accept that the first doesn't work... but I have to understand why only the last one is working.

Comment: I edited the question changing the method modifier (public to none), and now seems that the answer can be to switch it to public.... it is a bit strange, am i right?

Comment: You need to add `public` access modifier for the async method. It is on the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the third method (divide it in two beans) changing the async method's *access modifier* to `public`:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    MyAsyncService myAsyncService;

    public void worker() {
        myAsyncService.asyncJob();
    }
}

@Service
public class MyAsyncService {

    @Async
    public void asyncJob() { // switched to public
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 46):

Found a really nice way to solve this (with java8) in the case where you have a lot of various things you want to both sync and async. Instead of creating a separate `XXXAsync` service for each 'synchronous' service, create a generic async service wrapper:

```
@Service
public class AsyncService {

    @Async
    public void run(final Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

and then use it as such:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private AsyncService asyncService;


    public void refreshAsync() {
        asyncService.run(this::refresh);
    }


    public void refresh() {
        // my business logic
    }


    public void refreshWithParamsAsync(String param1, Integer param2) {
        asyncService.run(() -> this.refreshWithParams(param1, param2));
    }


    public void refreshWithParams(String param1, Integer param2) {
        // my business logic with parameters
    }

}
```

Comment: nice solution, but what if you needed to pass some params?

Comment: @denov extended my example to include a way to invoke with parameters using a lambda inplace of the Runnable interface

Comment: much better :)  i figured it out shortly after posting but i think it makes your answer a bit better.

Comment: What if we need to use separate thread pool for separate @async processes?

Comment: Wouldn't this run in its own thread and ignore the @Async and its thread pool

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was easier to remove the `@Async` annotation and use the `taskExecutor` directly to submit my task:

Before

```java
    @Async("taskExecutor")
    private Future<U> executerEnAsync(
            final T pInput) {

        final U resultat = this.appelerBS(pInput);
        return new AsyncResult<U>(resultat);

    }
```

After

```java
    @Autowired
    private AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    private Future<U> executerEnAsync(
            final T pInput) {

        final Future<U> future = taskExecutor.submit(new Callable<U>() {

            @Override
            public U call() {
                final U resultat = appelerBS(pInput);
                return resultat;
            }
        });

        return future;

    }
```